# C# Find ultimate parent with LINQ

Tags: linq, hierarchical

I have a hierarchical object with the following structure:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Folder> Child { get; set; }
}
```

If the folder is a root folder, the Parent will be `null`. If the folder is not a root the parent is `not null`.

I need to find the Ultimate parent of a Folder, that means, the root folder (`not null`) if exists one.

I would refer to avoid the while loop if possible. 
I would like to get it done using Linq expressions if possible.

Comment: Why avoid the while loop? Are you using LINQ to SQL or something similar? If this is LINQ to Objects, any LINQ-based solution you come up with will perform a loop of some sort, whether it's in your code or the LINQ code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why avoid the while loop if it is the fastest way to do it?

```
Folder root = myFolder;
while(root.Parent != null) root = myFolder.Parent;
```

Comment: Yes but this is done using a while loop. Is there a less expensive way?

Comment: @Raffaeu Any way you're going to do this with LINQ that I can think of is going to be much more expensive. I can't imagine anything being quicker or have a lower memory footprint.

Comment: Thank you I will use this for now.

Comment: Raffeau, if you don't understand feel free to ask more questions.  Don't just accept people's suggestions if you don't understand them.  Is there something about your implementation that's making this more expensive?

Comment: No I just try to avoid While loops as you can easily loose the control of them. Anyway I am satisfy about the overall performance of this function. Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking Linq is by far the most expensive (sane) way to do things. For simple loops it has a large overhead (which is worth it for the declarative nature of the code).